# maven error.... Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java

Tags: jdk, openjdk

I've just installed maven, but when I check the version of maven I get an error

```
$ mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined Correctly.
  We can not execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java
```

I check my home java

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure but mvn is adding `/bin/java` to your `$JAVA_HOME`
Try to set `$JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre`
Tell me if it's working  so that I write a more complete answer.